# How to fix Menu disappear issue while hover on specific page and working on all other page?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hover is working on some of the page and not working on some pages.
the menu does not hold on home and working fine on the rest of the pages.

**Not Working URL** : https://pcbmagic.com/

**Working URL** : https://pcbmagic.com/pcb-quote.php

```css
.dropdown-log {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: 1px solid rgb(111 111 111 / 65%);
    color: rgb(61, 79, 88);
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 13px;
    border-radius: 17px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.dropdown-log:hover .dropdown-log-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-log-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0;
    
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 220px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-log">
  <span>Hi,Vishal<i class="pl-2 fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
  <div class="dropdown-log-content">
  <div class="bg-dark py-2 mb-2">
        <div class="p-img">
            <svg style="height:30px;" fill="#21313C" viewBox="0 0 216.56 448.5" class="leafygreen-ui-1yq22vy"><path fill="#10aa50" d="M202.8,179.68c-23-101.47-71-128.49-83.18-147.59C113,21.7,106.25,5.91,106.25,5.91c-.66,9-1.83,14.7-9.51,21.54C81.36,41.16,16,94.42,10.51,209.72c-5.12,107.5,79,173.8,90.18,180.65,8.54,4.2,19,.08,24-3.77,40.54-27.84,96-102.07,78.06-206.92"></path><path fill="#b8c4c2" d="M109.73,333.11c-2.11,26.62-3.63,42.11-9,57.29,0,0,3.54,25.33,6,52.17l8.77,0a488.62,488.62,0,0,1,9.57-56.2C113.71,380.8,110.16,356.46,109.73,333.11Z"></path><path fill="#12924f" d="M125.06,386.39h0c-11.48-5.3-14.8-30.13-15.31-53.28A1090.8,1090.8,0,0,0,112.2,218.4c-.6-20.07.3-185.92-4.94-210.2,2.12,4.75,7.24,15.91,12.36,23.88,12.23,19.11,60.19,46.13,83.17,147.61C220.7,284.27,165.57,358.37,125.06,386.39Z"></path></svg>
        </div>
        <h6 class="text-center text-light">Vishal Vishwakarma</h6>
        <p class="text-center text-light" style="font-size:12px;">webadmin@championsemi.com</p>
    </div>
    <p><a href="/member/dashboard/">Dashboard</a></p>
    <p><a href="/member/dashboard/under-review.php">My Order</a></p>
    <p><a href="/member/dashboard/production.php">Production Status</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Help Center</a></p>
    <p><a href="/member/dashboard/logout.php">Logout</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.dropdown-log-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 220px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    z-index: 99999999;
}
```

add **z-index** as above in your code and it'll fix automatically. your bootstrap carousel is overlapping to that menu. that's the region why it's not getting hold.